# Proof the that compact support is a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Currently I am studying for my exam of Real Analysis, however there is one thing that I do not seem to get. Given:
$$
\mathrm{Supp}(f):=\overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)\neq 0\}}
$$
the support of $f$. If the support of $f$ is compact, then we have a compact support. Define:
$$
C_c(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}: f \text{ continous }, \mathrm{Supp}(f) \text{ compact}\}.
$$
Then $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a vectorspace.

For this we need to prove two things:

1. $\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \alpha\cdot f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ if }  f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$
2. if $f,g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\Rightarrow f+g\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$

However I already get stuck proving the first identity. My problem here is that I do not know if $\mathrm{Supp}(f)$ is compact. Could I get help proving that this is actually a vector space?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't the first one $0(x)\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$? (where $0(x)$ is the constant zero function)

Comment: What is meant with 1(x)? Is this the function 1(x) = 1 for all x?

Comment: Right, $1(x)=x , \forall x$ And Dario, maybe you are right, because if you look at $Supp(1(x))=\overline{\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(x)\neq 0\}}=\overline{\mathbb{R}^n}=\mathbb{R}^n$, but that set is not compact?

Comment: are you sure that it is 1(x) = x? That doesnt make any sense. To which vector space axiom would that correspond? Also this would not be a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Indeed it should be $0(x)\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, But we can leave that one out, because it is trivial that it is inside $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I will adjust my question.

Comment: "I do not know if $Supp(f)$ is compact" -- you want to prove that **if** it is compact, then $Supp (\alpha f)$ is also compact.

Answer (score 4):

The support of $\alpha f$ coincides with the support of $f$ for $\alpha\neq 0$, and the support of $f+g$ is contained in the union of $\mathrm{supp} (f)$ and $\mathrm{supp} (g)$ which shows that $\mathrm{supp} (f+g)$ is bounded. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, any bounded closed set is already compact.

Comment: Slightly stupid question maybe, but how is it that the support of $f+g$ is contained in support of $f$ union support of $g$, otherwise its clear now! Thank you

Comment: Outside of the support of f and g, everything is zero.

Comment: I'd avoid using boundedness, as the result is true for *any* topological space in place of $\mathbb{R}^n$; the union of two compact sets is compact and a closed subset of a compact set is compact.